# Fractional viewport and corresponding scissor rect

Tags: c++, graphics, direct3d

I am writing a modular class for D3D11 rendering, and a requirement I need to work with is to have the scissor test always enabled. This means that when a viewport is set, and I don't want to cull anything at the output merger stage, I would need to set the scissor rect to the size of the viewport. This isn't a problem for most cases, but I am wondering about the corner cases, where viewport can take FLOAT values for its dimensions and scissor rect only takes LONGs. This mismatch seems like a minor design flaw in D3D11, but that's beside the point. I am wondering what I should set my scissor rect to be, when I have a fractional viewport? It looks like we have two options:

```
scissorRect.right= static_cast<LONG>(viewport.TopLeftX + viewport.Width))
```

Directly cast to LONG and lose the precision: This means that a small part of the scene will be culled unnecessarily.

```
scissorRect.right= static_cast<LONG>(ceil(viewport.TopLeftX + viewport.Width)))
```

Floor or ceil the floating point value prior to casting to LONG: This means it's possible that the scissor rect for a particular rendering operation might extend beyond the intended bound, or even the size of the window.

I am inclined to go with the latter option because it doesn't seem like it can pose any harm since the viewport will limit the bound of the rendering operations anyways, so we won't overdraw or draw outside the window. What do you guys think?

Please let me know. 
Thanks.